Authentication issue with Azure AD-integrated application: Admin Approval Required
I am reaching out to seek assistance with an issue that we are encountering an authentication issue when users attempt to access our application, which is registered in Azure Active Directory (Azure AD)
Description of the Issue:
When attempting to access Microsoft Project, users are being prompted with an "Admin Approval Required" message despite having been granted all necessary permissions and scopes within the application. The error message states,
"Need admin approval. This app may be risky. If you trust this app, please ask your admin to grant you access."
Affected User(s):
Multiple users within our organization in the same tenant directory experienced this issue.
Steps Taken:
We have thoroughly reviewed and ensured that the affected users have been granted all necessary permissions and scopes within our application.
Additionally, we have checked the OAuth consent settings to confirm that they are configured correctly and have grant admin consent for default directory Under the API permission and under the Enterprise Application.
We have also cleared cache and cookies, and tested the issue from different devices and networks, but the problem persists.
Additional Information:
We are using the latest version of Microsoft Project(ASP.NET CORE MVC ).
Users are accessing Microsoft Project via web browser.
Our organization utilizes Single Sign-On (SSO) for authentication.
I'm using /common as authority.(https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token")
Under the Microsoft Entra Admin Center we have enabled the Admin consent requests - Users can request admin consent to apps they are unable to consent to.
But still when a user try to authenticate to application, Need admin approval message has been shown. Instead of this it should open the Approval required dialog box but it is not prompting this.
API permission image
Admin Consent Settings Image
Error Image

Does this answer your question? Need admin approval unverified This app may be risky. If you trust this app, please ask your admin to grant you access

I agree with @esqew, newly registered multitenant apps will require verified publishers in order for end users to grant consent. Therefore, it seems that we will need to publish your app before allowing sign-ins from multi-tenant accounts.
If still the issue persists, check the below:
Note that: When a user signs in, their authentication will be based on the settings of their home tenant, rather than the tenant where the application is located. If you are using common or organizations to authenticate the user, it's important to ensure that the user's home tenant has the appropriate settings in place.
Created a Microsoft Entra ID application and granted API permissions like below:

When I tried to login with other tenant user, I got the same error:
For sample, I used the below endpoint to authenticate users
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&state=12345


Hence to resolve the error, check the user consent settings in the directory/tenant where the user resides and Set Admin consent requests to YES:

Then the user will get the Approval required screen to request for the access. Once it gets approved user will be able to access the app.
Reference:
javascript - How to implement user consent in applications multitenant registered with Azure AD B2 with microsoft graph to access Microsoft Calendar API? - Stack Overflow by me
